# Finding the likelihood ratio test from a binomial distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, likelihood-ratio

I'm having a bit of troubles getting a working rejection region out of this problem:

Let $X_{1},....X_{n}$ be a random sample from $Binomial$($1,p$) distribution. Assume that $n=5$. We test $H_{0} : p = \frac{1}{2}$ against $H_{1}: p \neq \frac{1}{2}$. Find:

$i)$ The likelihood ratio test

$ii)$ The rejection region when the size of the test is $0.05$

My work so far:

Let $\ddot{x}=(x_{1},...,x_{5})$

then:

$L(p,\ddot{x})$ = $p^{\sum_{i=1}^5 x_{i}}$ $(1-p)^{\sum_{i=1}^5 (1-x_{i})}$ $\sqcap_{i=1}^{5} \mathbb{1}_{{S}}(x_{i})$ where $S =${$0,1$}

I found the MLE of $p$ under $ H_{0}$$\bigcup$$H_{1}$ $=$ $\bar{X}$

With a bit of simplifying the LRT Statistic is then:

$\lambda(\ddot{x})= \frac{\frac{1}{32}}{\bar{x}^{\sum_{i=1}^5 x_{i}}(1-\bar{x})^{5 -\sum_{i=1}^5 x_{i}}}$ where $x_{i}\in${$0,1$} for $i=1,...5$

We reject $H_{0}$ $IFF$:
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{1}{32}}{\bar{x}^{\sum_{i=1}^5 x_{i}}(1-\bar{x})^{5 -\sum_{i=1}^5 x_{i}}} \leq k 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\leftrightarrow {\bar{x}^{\sum_{i=1}^5 x_{i}}(1-\bar{x})^{5 -\sum_{i=1}^5 x_{i}}} \geq k^{'} 
\end{align}

This is where I get stuck I don't see a suitable way to simplify this to a point where I have a nice rejection region for the likelihood ratio test, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by understanding (and using) that $\hat p = x/n.$ 
Also, by relying on your intuition that you're going to reject
for observed *integers* $x$ far from 2.5.

Your criterion is to reject if $Q = \hat p^x(1-\hat p)^{n-x}$ is large.
Make a plot (I'm using R, but calculator, pencil, and paper will do.)

```
n = 5;  x = 0:n;  p = x/n
q = p^x*(1-p)^{n-x}
plot(x, q, pch=19)
```

[image]

The first thing to try would be to reject only for $x = 0$ or $5.$ Using the binomial formula, that gives rejection probability under the null hypothesis $H_0: p = 1/2$ as $2/32 = 1/16 = 0.0625.$

```
sum(dbinom(c(0,5), 5, .5))
[1] 0.0625
```

So the smallest size for a non-randomized test is 6.25%.
For a test at exactly 5%, you would have to use a randomized test. I'll leave that part to you.